# swig.exe gives error illegal token É on creating C# wrapper

Tags: swig

i'm using swig tool to create c# wrapper for a dll.i used command `swig.exe -csharp modbusm.dll` but gives error `illegal token`
[image]

i have also downloaded latest swig from github and compiled using minGW, but give same error. am i using Swig in right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to provide your .dll as input for SWIG. Instead, you have to create an [interface file](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn5) that will contain the function and variable declarations that will be wrapped.

Comment: can share a good article url for creating interface for native dll files ?

Comment: @jobinelv I believe you should start with the SWIG documentation. SWIG is too big to be covered by small tutorials. Plus, the documentation is pretty extensive, with several examples.